# How to redirect from folder to subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

How to redirect with domain

```
site.com/image/some_symbols
```

to subdomain

```
some_symbols.site.com/
```

I've tried so

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|)site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^image/(+*)$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.%{HTTP_HOST}/$ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%{REQUEST_URI}` starts from the `/` at the beginning; which is why your pattern was not successful.

Better yet, do not rely on another `RewriteCond`, keeping it simply as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?site\.com$
RewriteRule ^image/(.+)$ http://$1.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to change that `.+` to `\w[\w.-]+\w` as subdomains cannot contain slashes etc. - just a failsafe.